# Fast method to get a unique identity for video files

Tags: python, video, hash, hashlib

I need a unique hash for video files, which can handle the following:
- Change in filename
- Change in file location
- Two files with exactly the same filesize, but different contents within (should be treated as different files)

Now while the hashing algorithms like md5, sha1 seem to be a good candidate, I need something which takes fraction of seconds to produce.
On a 2GB video file, it takes 5 sec to produce the md5 checksum value.
I assume the long processing time is natural because of having to read the large video file.

Is there something I could use, which specifically utilizes the properties of video files, maybe does the comparison just using video file headers or something. Goal here is to obtain the unique video id in fraction of seconds.

Comment: I am struggling with the exact same problem myself. Have you found a satisfactory solution which works reasonably fast.

Answer (score 1):

As a first approach, I would consider taking crc32 from first 10 Mb plus maybe file size. You will have collisions with this method and will need to handle them but all hashing algorithms have collisions.

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you can use utility `ffprobe` (which comes with `ffmpeg`) to get video headers and compute md5 from them. But running it as a process will be slow and it seems it doesn't exist as a python library to import.

Comment: Right. Thanks for your suggestions. Had thought of this. But looking for something more elegant, given that video headers could help here.. (and hence avoid collision with much higher probability). Video file headers are not necessarily located at the beginning of the video file.